# I want to clear my table data before adding new data from the api request? i have tried to use multiple methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

```
$("#artistButton").on('click', function () {
var artist = $("#artistSearch").val().trim()
var queryURL = "https://rest.bandsintown.com/artists/" + artist + "/events?app_id=test&date=upcoming" + artist + "?app_id=test";
console.log(artist)


$.ajax({
    url: queryURL,
    method: "GET"
}).then(function (response) {
    var imageURL = response[0].artist.image_url;
    var image = $("<img id='pictureSize'>")
    var artistName = response[0].artist.name

    console.log(response)


    $("#artistName").html(artistName)
    image.attr('src', imageURL)
    $("#artistImage").html(image)
    $("#venue").html(response[125].venue.name)



    for (var i = 0; i < response.length || 5; i++) {
        var time = moment(response[i].datetime).format("MMM Do, hh:mm");
        var venueName = response[i].venue.name
        var city = response[i].venue.city;
        var region = response[i].venue.region
        if (i == 5) {
            break;
        }

        $(".tableData").before($("<tr><td>" + venueName + "</td>" + "<td>" + city + ', ' + region + "</td>" + "<td>" + time + "</td></tr>"))
    }
});

$(".tableData").val("");
```

})

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery clear HTML table and insert new rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558881/jquery-clear-html-table-and-insert-new-rows)

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to answer my own question in case someone had the same issue but i simply added $("#concertInfo").find("td").remove(); after my ajax call and it will remove all table data!

Comment: You can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60087267/9071943) to have a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`empty`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) or [`remove`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/#remove-selector) function to set the table content before adding new ones.

- Empty: *"Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM."*
- Remove: *"Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM."*